# Inequality with an absolute value of Brownian Motion

Tags: inequality, brownian-motion, supremum-and-infimum

I know how to prove this equation:
$$ \forall a>0 \ \  P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) \leq e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}
,
$$
where $B(t)$ is a Brownian Motion

Firstly, I have to prove that $ e^{c B(t)} $ is submartingale (c is constant), next I use Doob's Inequality and I have my thesis.

Now I have similar inequality like this:
$$ \forall a>0 \ \  P(\sup_{s \leq t}|B(s)| \geq a) \leq 2 e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}
$$

Can I do something like that:

$$ P(\sup_{s \leq t}|B(s)| \geq a) = P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) + P(\inf_{s \leq t}B(s) \leq -a) = P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) + P(-\inf_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) = P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) + P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) = 2 P(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a) \leq 2 e^{-\frac{a^2}{2t}}
$$

Comment: Yeah, that's correct...

Comment: I may have missed something. For the first equality, are the two sets $(\sup_{s \leq t}B(s) \geq a)$ and $(\inf_{s \leq t}B(s) \leq -a)$ disjoint?

Comment: I think no :/, so my solution is not correct